# How does Instabot perform actions in the browser?

Tags: python, browser

How do services like Instabot perform UI driven actions from the terminal? Are they using some headless browser automation or some other technique?

https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py

Comment: Did you not wonder what's in that `src` folder?

Comment: Yes, I've been reading the source code. Not familiar with the Python landscape so I can't tell if just curl requests are being made or some tool is being used for headless browser automation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py/blob/master/requirements.txt, it pretty much only uses the `requests` library, which does not do browser automation.